# Generation and summation of series of natural numbers for a list of numbers

Tags: python

I am new to python and was hoping someone can help me with a question from my practice. I am trying to create a function that would add the sums of numbers in list starting from 1 for each number. For example, [4,2,3] should return the result of

```
((1+2+3+4) + (1+2) + (1+2+3)) = 19
```

Comment: Sounds like a nice problem to help you learn python. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What does one divided by python mean in your question? It's the `1 / python` I don't understand.

Comment: Its definitely a tough one haha, just a beginner to coding. I tried multiple functions  but none of them were close and all were far off the result i was seeking.

Comment: I think the slash is meant to be a divider, `[question] / python`

Comment: yes! just a slash! my apologies!

Comment: @JassyDhu Post a solution you've attempted so we can give you some better guidance. Without something for us to work off of we are basically just telling you the answer which won't benefit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
lists = [4,3,2]

total = 0

for data in lists:

  for c in range(data):

    n = c+1

    total += n

print total
```

Comment: Thank you so much, spent hours on this but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I won't just give you an answer, but I will show you a process that will help you break down this problem (and others you'll encounter later on).

Take a look at your goal:

You want to be able to pass in a list of integers, such as `[4,2,3]` and return the result of the sums starting from 1 to each of the integers of the list.

Try to break this into as many parts as you can:

How do I pass in a list of integers to a function?
How do I do something on every element of a list?
Given just one integer `n` (One element of the list), how do I calculate the sum of all numbers `1 + 2 + ... + n` ?
How can I return that number?

I feel like the most important part of this task is to, given an integer, calculate the sum of all numbers up to that. Fortunately, there exists a mathematical expression for this. Given a number `n`, the sum of all natural numbers less than or equal to `n` is `(n)(n+1) / 2` . If you haven't seen that formula before, try it out a few times. `(1)(1+1) / 2 = 2 / 2 = 1` , `2(2+1)/2 = 6/2 = 3`, `(3)(3+1) / 2 = 12/2 = 6`. It works well.

The next part I'd focus on is how to do this for every element in the list. How about a loop where we iterate over every element of the list? This is done by:

```
for i in your_list:
    ... #Enter code you want to happen for every element here
```

In case you aren't familiar with how these loops work, the loop is repeated for every element of the list, and `i` (Or whatever variable you want, `_` is a really common one too) becomes the element of the list. So if you did

```
your_list = [5,4,3,6]
for i in your_list:
    print(i)
```

the output would be

```
5
4
3
6
```

So lets try it with the addition formula from the last step.

```
your_list = [4,2,3]
for i in your_list:
    natural_sum = (i)*(i+1)/2
    print(natural_sum)
```

Output:

```
10
3
6
```

So now we're getting our addition numbers, but we don't want to print them, we want to add them all up. This is part of the returning the value step. We want to return the whole amount. Let's call this `tot_sum` for total_sum. First we'll initialize it to zero, then in the loop we'll add the `natural_sum`s we're coming up with to the total_sum.

```
tot_sum = 0
your_list = [4,2,3]
for i in your_list:
    natural_sum = (i)*(i+1)/2
    tot_sum += natural_sum
return tot_sum
```

However returning `tot_sum` doesn't make much sense yet because we aren't in a function. This is part of the first thing we identified: How do we pass in a function? Well, like this:

```
def your_sum(your_list):
    tot_sum = 0

    for i in your_list:
        natural_sum = (i)*(i+1)/2
        tot_sum += natural_sum
    return tot_sum

 #Then call it
 print(your_sum([4,2,3]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything makes sense but I'm definitely gonna practice the steps and ensure I know the method! Much appreciated!